# How can I add an image to Stripe's Checkout Session page as a Buffer / Binary instead of a URL

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, binary-data

When I try to create a checkout session without the image, it is working as expected. But When I add the "images: [`data ..." line in the product_data object, I am getting the error: `Invalid URL: URL must be 2048 characters or less.` This is a pretty big problem because when storing the images as binary, it obviously ends up being far more than 2048 characters. Are there any workarounds for this? Does Stripe provide a way to pass in images as binary instead of urls? Or can I somehow create a temporary url so it works inside the checkout session? Or am I out of luck here unless I change to paying for an image hosting service to get a url?

```
router.post('/create-checkout-session', get_user, get_cart_unformatted, async (req, res) => {

    // create line_items
    let line_items = []  
    await req.cart.line_items.forEach(async item => {
        line_items.push({
            price_data: {
                currency: user.currency,
                product_data: {
                    name: item.product_name,
                    images: [`data:image/${item.image.image.contentType};base64,${item.image.image.data.toString('base64')}`],
                },
                unit_amount: Math.round(item.price * 100),
            },
            quantity: item.quantity,
        });
    });

    // create checkout page
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        shipping_address_collection: {
            allowed_countries: ['AC', 'AD', /*... (all countries)*/, 'ZM', 'ZW'],
        },
        shipping_options: [{ /*...(not important for this question)*/ }],
        mode: 'payment',
        allow_promotion_codes: true,
        line_items: line_items,
        success_url: `${ process.env.SERVER_URL }shop/success`,
        cancel_url: req.body.url,
    });
    res.json({ url: session.url });

});
```

Here is a picture showing the structure of my image obejct inside `item.image`

[image: The image object]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this is possible. Stripe requires a URL if you're passing  `line_items.price_data.product_data.images` when creating a Checkout Session. This means you'd need to host those images somewhere first. If you create Product objects prior to creating the Checkout Session, you could upload product images using the Stripe Dashboard.